# Fast modular multiplication modulo prime for linear congruential generator in C

Tags: c, random, primes, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to implement a random-number generator with Mersenne prime (2<sup>31</sup>-1) as the modulus. The following working code was based on several related posts:

1. [How do I extract specific 'n' bits of a 32-bit unsigned integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011700/how-do-I-extract-specific-n-bits-of-a-32-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c)
2. [Fast multiplication and subtraction modulo a prime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914637/fast-multiplication-and-subtraction-modulo-a-prime)
3. [Fast multiplication modulo 2^16 + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939351/fast-multiplication-modulo-216-1)

However,

It does not work with `uint32_t hi, lo;`, which means I do not understand signed vs. unsigned aspect of the problem.

Based on #2 above, I was expecting the answer to be (hi+lo). Which means, I do not understand why the following statement is needed.

```
   if (x1 > r)
        x1 += r + 2;
```

- Can someone please clarify the source of my confusion?
- Can the code itself be improved?
- Should the generator avoid 0 or 2<sup>31</sup>-1 as a seed?
- How would the code change for a prime (2<sup>p</sup>-k)?

#### Original code

```
#include <inttypes.h>
// x1 = a*x0 (mod 2^31-1)
int32_t lgc_m(int32_t a, int32_t x)
{
    printf("x %"PRId32"\n", x);
    if (x == 2147483647){
    printf("x1 %"PRId64"\n", 0); 
        return (0);
    }
    uint64_t  c, r = 1;
    c = (uint64_t)a * (uint64_t)x;
    if (c < 2147483647){
        printf("x1 %"PRId64"\n", c); 
        return (c);
    }
    int32_t hi=0, lo=0;
    int i, p = 31;//2^31-1
    for (i = 1; i < p; ++i){
       r |= 1 << i;
    }
   lo = (c & r) ;
   hi = (c & ~r) >> p;
   uint64_t x1 = (uint64_t ) (hi + lo);
   // NOT SURE ABOUT THE NEXT STATEMENT
   if (x1 > r)
        x1 += r + 2; 
   printf("c %"PRId64"\n", c);
   printf("r %"PRId64"\n", r);
   printf("\tlo %"PRId32"\n", lo);
   printf("\thi %"PRId32"\n", hi);
   printf("x1 %"PRId64"\n", x1); 
   printf("\n" );
   return((int32_t) x1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int32_t r;
    r = lgc_m(1583458089, 1);
    r = lgc_m(1583458089, 2000000000);
    r = lgc_m(1583458089, 2147483646);
    r = lgc_m(1583458089, 2147483647);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Look at the assembler output of the sgined operations.  You will generally see Logical Shifts to the Left, but Arithmetic Shifts to the Right with signed values.  Other bitwise operators should behave the same.  The ASL operator will preserve the sign bits when shifting downwards.

Comment: Thanks. The first attempt was signed and therefore added to the confusion. The second solution used unsigned and revealed the real problem.

Comment: `uint64_t x1 = (uint64_t ) ((hi + lo) );`  Hmmm  maybe `uint64_t x1 = (uint64_t ) hi + lo;`?

Comment: Minor: `r |= 1 << i;` --> `r |= (uint32_t)1 << i;`  (Cope with 16-bit `int`. and signed overflow.)

Comment: @chux. Thanks for catching these errors!

Comment: `r |=1` part just creates the modulus `r = m = 2147483647`. Hard coding this eliminates the issue.

Comment: It would be nicer to remove the solution from the question, post it as an answer (what it is !) and accept it. Currently, the question appears as a not answered one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following if statement

```
if (x1 > r)
    x1 += r + 2;
```

should be written as

```
if (x1 > r)
    x1 -= r;
```

Both results are the same modulo 2^31:

```
x1 + r + 2 = x1 + 2^31 - 1 + 2 = x1 + 2^31 + 1
x1 - r = x1 - (2^31 - 1) = x1 - 2^31 + 1
```

The first solution overflows an `int32_t` and assumes that conversion from `uint64_t` to `int32_t` is modulo 2^31. While many C compilers handle the conversion this way, this is not mandated by the C standard. The actual result is implementation-defined.

The second solution avoids the overflow and works with both `int32_t` and `uint32_t`.

You can also use an integer constant for `r`:

```
uint64_t r = 0x7FFFFFFF; // 2^31 - 1
```

Or simply

```
uint64_t r = INT32_MAX;
```

**EDIT:** For primes of the form 2^p-k, you have to use masks with p bits and calculate the result with

```
uint32_t x1 = (k * hi + lo) % ((1 << p) - k)
```

If `k * hi + lo` can overflow a `uint32_t` (that is `(k + 1) * (2^p - 1) >= 2^32`), you have to use 64-bit arithmetic:

```
uint32_t x1 = ((uint64_t)a * x) % ((1 << p) - k)
```

Depending on the platform, the latter might be faster anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Even though, the code 'worked' I did not really understand what was going on.  Your answer addresses all points of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Sue provided this as a solution:

> With some experimentation (new code at the bottom), I was able to use
>   `uint32_t`, which further suggests that I do not understand how the
>   signed integers work with bit operations.
>
> The following code uses `uint32_t` for input as well as `hi` and `lo`.
>
> ```
>  #include <inttypes.h>
>   // x1 = a*x0 (mod 2^31-1)
>  uint32_t lgc_m(uint32_t a, uint32_t x)
>   {
>     printf("x %"PRId32"\n", x);
>     if (x == 2147483647){
>     printf("x1 %"PRId64"\n", 0); 
>         return (0);
>     }
>     uint64_t  c, r = 1;
>     c = (uint64_t)a * (uint64_t)x;
>     if (c < 2147483647){
>         printf("x1 %"PRId64"\n", c); 
>         return (c);
>     }
>     uint32_t hi=0, lo=0;
>     int i, p = 31;//2^31-1
>     for (i = 1; i < p; ++i){
>        r |= 1 << i;
>     }
>    hi = c >> p;
>    lo = (c & r) ;
>    uint64_t x1 = (uint64_t ) ((hi + lo) );
>    // NOT SURE ABOUT THE NEXT STATEMENT
>    if (x1 > r){
>        printf("x1 - r = %"PRId64"\n", x1- r);
>            x1 -= r; 
>    }
>    printf("c %"PRId64"\n", c);
>    printf("r %"PRId64"\n", r);
>    printf("\tlo %"PRId32"\n", lo);
>    printf("\thi %"PRId32"\n", hi);
>    printf("x1 %"PRId64"\n", x1); 
>    printf("\n" );
>    return((uint32_t) x1);
>   }
>
>   int main(void)
>  {
>     uint32_t r;
>     r = lgc_m(1583458089, 1583458089);
>     r = lgc_m(1583458089, 2147483645);
>     return(0);
>   }
> ```
>
> The issue was that my assumption that the reduction will be complete
>   after one pass. If (x > 2<sup>31</sup>-1), then by definition the
>   reduction has not occurred and a second pass is necessary. Subtracting
>   2<sup>31</sup>-1, in that case does the trick. In the second attempt
>   above, `r = 2^31-1` and is therefore the modulus. `x -= r` achieves
>   the final reduction.
>
> Perhaps someone with expertise in random numbers or modular reduction
>   could explain it better.
>
> Cleaned function without `printf()`s.
>
> ```
> uint32_t lgc_m(uint32_t a, uint32_t x){
>     uint64_t c, x1, m = 2147483647; //modulus: m = 2^31-1
>     if (x == m)
>         return (0);
>     c = (uint64_t)a * (uint64_t)x;
>     if (c < m)//no reduction necessary
>         return (c);
>     uint32_t hi, lo, p = 31;//2^p-1, p = 31 
>     hi = c >> p;
>     lo = c & m;
>     x1 = (uint64_t)(hi + lo);
>     if (x1 > m){//one more pass needed 
>        //this block can be replaced by x1 -= m;
>         hi = x1 >> p;
>         lo = (x1 & m);
>         x1 = (uint64_t)(hi + lo);
>     }
>    return((uint32_t) x1);
> }
> ```